# Passing event data in the inline event handlers

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

I have an `<input>` which has an `onkeydown` inline event handler. In this handler, I'd like to call a function and pass a special parameter to it - the event data.

When I want to handle events (e.g. onmousemove) for the whole document, I use the following code:

```
document.onmousemove=function(e) {
// here I can make a good use of the 'e' variable,
// for example extract the mouse coordinates from it
}
```

And it works (although I don't know where the `e` variable - event data - comes from).
But this time I want to use the function only for the `<input>` mentioned above.
I need to pass the event data to the function so it can get the pressed key's code. And I want to do it in that inline event handler. I've created a function:

```
function myfunc (e) {
    var evt=window.event?event:e;
    var code=evt.keyCode;
    alert (code);
}
```

and tried all of these methods:

`<input onkeydown="myfunc(this)">`

`<input onkeydown="myfunc(this.onkeydown)">`

`<input onkeydown="myfunc(onkeydown)">`

But none of them worked, the alert window kept displaying "undefined".
I looked for a solution to my problem in Google, but didn't find anything that could help me solve it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`<input onkeydown="myfunc(event)">`

```
function myfunc (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var code = e.keyCode;
    alert (code);
}
```

Comment: Line ´e = e || window.event´ throws warning is Visual Studio `Warning TS6385 (JS) 'event' is deprecated`. Please fix answer to use standard compatible code.